# Is there a way to get the Owner User ID of a Facebook Page via php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing a web system but I need to get the User id of owner facebook page that add my app, but I need to get it even if not have any authentication, is there a way to do it?

I tried FQL, it works but needs auth.

Edit: I got the page id but I need to get the user id of the owner of this page id, but I need to get it without any authentication.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine who the owner of a page is without being authorized to do so.